# can one class extends from multiple classes php

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance

I have one class that should extend two classes I'm not sure anymore if this is possible and how. would it be possible that for example my shopModell class extends from the logins and safeinput class?

Comment: Not possible with PHP. You might be able to use [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for your design though.

Comment: okay thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use inheritance with classes.
e.g `class Foo extends Bar { //your code }`
With two classes you must use dependecies.